# soap response error

Tags: iphone

I am doing soap request/response application. While building soap response, I am getting "Server did not recognize the value of HTTP Header SOAPAction".

What does that mean? And how to solve this?

Here is the code.

```
NSString *soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<SignOn xmlns=\"http://10.12.50.99/CUTechWebservices/CuTechWebService.asmx\">\n"
                         "<DeviceID>4A6B740C-0B5B-5F8C-8694-1EC0196C1C67</DeviceID>\n"
                         "<UserID>10827</UserID>\n"
                         "<CrID>6</CrID>\n"
                         "<UserPin>777777!</UserPin>\n"
                         "</SignOn>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>\n"];    
NSLog(@"%@",soapMessage);

//Soap request.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mobile.areafinancial.com/cutechservice/cutechwebservice.asmx"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[soapMessage length]];
[theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue:@"http://10.12.50.99/CUTechWebservices/CuTechWebService.asmx" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SOAP 1.2 `SOAPAction` header was replaced with "optional" `action` attribute of `Content-Type` header field.

Try it with following header:

```
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8; action="https://mobile.areafinancial.com/cutechservice/cutechwebservice.asmx?op=SignOn"
```

without the `SOAPAction:` header field.

See also http://www.coderanch.com/t/224524/Web-Services/java/SOAPAction-header

Comment: I tried this. but this time i am getting error "Unable to handle request. The action 'https://mobile.areafinancial.com/cutechservice/cutechwebservice.asmx?op=SignOn' was not recognized."

Comment: Try `http://10.12.50.99/CUTechWebservices/CuTechWebService.asmx/SignOn` as the action. I just found out it by downloading https://mobile.areafinancial.com/cutechservice/cutechwebservice.asmx?WSDL and searching for a soapAction string.

Comment: @peter that is what I actually did. And its working perfectly. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove below line and see what you get. This header you passed in request. You should pass same header as in the web service.

```
[theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```